# Integration of refinery cms in rails 4 existing application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

How to integrate refinery cms in existing rails 4 application.

I have already added in gemfile this gem 'refinerycms-i18n', 
github: 'refinery/refinerycms-i18n', branch: 'master' 
gem 'refinerycms', github: 'refinery/refinerycms', branch: "master"

and I tried to do

`rails g refinery:engine app name:string description:text`

but the error is 
`Could not find generator refinery:engine`.

How to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never do this, but here there is a official: [Guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app) I hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks for your reply #Riccardo Degan I have done same like that but still it was not working

Answer (score 1):

Was doing some research on this same topic.  Currently the docs state that "Refinery CMS is not compatible with Rails 4".  Please update your answer if you find this to not be the case!

Source: [RefineryCMS Getting Started](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#rails-application-templates)